# addEventListener does not call API properly

Tags: javascript, async-await

#### problem:

First, when I click the button, nothing is displayed in the console.

The second time I click the button, the console shows a response.

The third time, when I click the button, the console shows the response twice

#### expectations:

when I press the button, I expect to see the response displayed in the console.

#### Requirements

There may be no button.(Button are dynamic elements)

- index.js

```
import { actionTest } from "./modules/action";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  actionTest();
});
```

- modules/action.js

```
import { fetchApi } from "../store/store";

/**
 * call api
 */
async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetchApi();
  return res;
}

/**
 * action
 */
export function actionTest() {
  const btnElem = document.querySelector(".test-btn");
  if (btnElem !== null) {
    btnElem.addEventListener(
      "click",
      () => {
        const res = fetchData();
        if (res) {
          console.log(res);
        }
      },
      false
    );
  }
}
document.addEventListener("click", actionTest, false);
```

- store/store.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export async function fetchApi() {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

Comment: you forgot the `await` keyword when calling the `fetchData` method inside the `actionTest` method

Comment: I can't understand. .Adding async / await to actionTest() is a syntax error.

Comment: `actionTest()` adds a click handler on a dynamic button (bad planning). Then `actionTest()` handles all clicks occurring anywhere (ie document)? So any click will add another listener to the same button?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're experiencing is due to a couple of things. The event you're initially binding to is DomContentLoaded. This event fires after all the DOM Content has been loaded (HTML Text), it does not wait for any scripts or stylesheets to complete loading before firing. In which case you'll want to use the "Load" event.

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
  actionTest();
});
```

This will get you your immediate first console log when all the scripts have successfully completed downloading and have been parsed by the browser.

The next issue is with the placement of the button click handler. Every time you call actiontest() you're adding another, different event handler to the button.

Instead maybe try something like this...

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
   /* Delegate the event to be captured by the document
      this will ensure that dynamic buttons are captured without 
      having to explicitly assign an event handler to each button
      when it is added to the dom, instead the event will bubble up to the 
      document to be handled.
   */
   document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
      if(evt.target.matches('.test-btn')){
          actionTest();
      }
   }, false);


   // execute initial call
   actionTest();
})

export function actionTest() {
  const res = fetchData();
  if (res) {
     console.log(res);
  }
}
```

This should show only one `console.log` initially and then a single `console.log` for every subsequent click on the button.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion :

```js
const fetchAPI = () => new Promise(resolve=>resolve("this is data")) //for test

window.onload = () =>{
    console.log("loaded..")
    document.getElementsByClassName("test-btn")[0].onclick = async() =>{
          console.log("clicked")
          const res = await fetchAPI()
          console.log(res)
       }
}
```

```html
<button class="test-btn">test-button</button>
```

Comment: I try.. but SyntaxError
SyntaxError: /src/modules/action.js: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: you have to clear event listner before adding 2nd one

Comment: I think you dont have to add event lister again and again. only one time enough ?

Comment: All issues have been resolved. I shouldn't have added event listeners many times. Thank you for your advice. Thank you.